# How to show alert message with php?

Tags: php, html

I make some changes in my php code, it works. I just want now if the user enter the login and password that i wanted correct, new page appear with a message for exemple saying "congratulations". In my case always it moves to the last line

```
header("WWW-Authenticate: Basic realm='Access denied'");
```

which appears a new form of filling the login and password. Even, I fill them , it will ask me again and show me the form another time. How can i fixed?

my HTML code:

```html
<html>

<head>
</head>

<body>

  <form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="verify_user.php">
    <p align="center">Username :
      <input type="text" name="AUTH_USER " id="AUTH_USER " />
    </p>
    <p align="center">Password :
      <input type="password" name="AUTH_PASS" id="AUTH_PASS" />
    </p>
    <p align="center">
      <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Login" />
    </p>
  </form>
  <h3 align="center" class="para">
    <?php
    if(isset($_GET['id'])) {
    echo $_GET['id'];
     }
    ?>
  </h3>
</body>

</html>
```

my PHP code:

```php
<?php
function require_auth() {

    $AUTH_USER = 'MAYAR12';
    $AUTH_PASS = '*******';


    // header('Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate, max-age=0');
   if( $has_supplied_credentials = !(empty($_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER']) && empty($_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_PASS']))){
       echo "<script>alert('congratulations');</script>";
   }
    $is_not_authenticated = (
        !$has_supplied_credentials ||
        $_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER'] != $AUTH_USER ||
        $_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_PASS']   != $AUTH_PASS
    );
    if ($is_not_authenticated) {
        echo "<script>alert('erreur');</script>";


         header("WWW-Authenticate: Basic realm='Access denied'");

    }
}
require_auth();
?>
```

Comment: Is require_auth function being called anywhere in your code?

Comment: Please learn how to indent your code properly in the future. Thank you

Comment: What have you tried to debug the problem? A white page might indicate that there is some fatal error?

Comment: How can i call this function in my HTML code? because i didn't call it anywhere.

Comment: Actually i don't know the main problem. I'm triing to change my code and make some new alert message or even simple one, maybe it will work. But nothing happen. If i make a message and it works, the message will appear and then the page will not be white again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use this :

```
 echo "<script>alert('alert message');</script>";
```